# Possible to provide an instance delegate vs static in my C# class for use in Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, static, instance, func

Is there a simpler way to express this Func?  Or to call it as an instance method, rather than static?

The goal is to eliminate all of the complexity of the search in the view/UI code ...

If I have a class (FilterDetail) with a set of bool values, grouped as strings for comparison to a list of items ... in a legacy database.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Locations => new List<string> { AsOne, AsTwo, AsThree, AsFour, AsFive, AsSix };
```

And I provide this ...

```
public static Func<FilterDetail, string, bool> LocationFilter = (item, loc) => 
    item.Locations.Any(x => x.Equals(loc, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

So in my view I can just:

```
 calls = calls.Where(x => FilterDetail.LocationFilter(Filter, x.Location_Abbr))
```

Is there a way, using Linq, to just use a function from the instance of FilterDetail (Filter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an instance method if you have an object available.

Assuming `FilterDetail Filter` is an object in scope, then

```
calls = calls.Where(x => Filter.LocationFilter(x.Location_Abbr));
```

The `LocationFilter` method would need to be changed:

```
public bool LocationFilter(string)
{
  return this.Locations.Any(x => x.Equals(loc, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that already ... C# 10 gives me a CS0236 error ... A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field ... Locations (with or without the redundant this qualifier)

Comment: I edited my answer because I goofed. The `LocationFilter` method should be returning `bool`, not a `Func`. And it should be an actual instance method, not a field.

Comment: Of course, … I was overthinking it.